# Does the Quick Search Box search the database in Android? how?

Tags: database, android, sqlite, android-mapview, android-searchmanager

i have an database with the values of latitude and longitude. i would need to search those values depends on the user input. does the quick search box can search only the database value with the type-to-search feature. Else i want to put a separate EditText and then do the the search process.. if QSB is possible then how to do that? i want to search and drop a pin on the map.. please make a note of it. Any Idea, tutorial and sample codes are most thankful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation, examples and sample code on the Android Developers' [Quick Search Box](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html) article.

As the QSB gets its results from a `ContentProvider`, you can implement searching of one or more databases or any data source you like.

Comment: this is not enough to understand.can you give me some sample code or tutorials to do that?

Comment: Did you see the sample code on Android's site that I linked to? That, along with all the explanation on that page, should be all you need if you understand Android and Java.